# Splitting string using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string using preg_split, but I want to include the delimiters, and I don't want to capture an empty string. How would I do this?

```
$inputX = "hello1.hello2.";
$tempInput = preg_split( "~(\?|\.|!|\,)~", $inputX); //split the input at .!?,
print_r($tempInput)
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => hello1 [1] => hello2 [2] => )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => hello1. [1] => hello2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=[.!?])(?!$|[.!?])
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eW9tC6/4)

Explaining:

```
(?<=          # looks for positions after
    [.!?]     # one of these three characters
)             #
(?!           # but not
    $         # at the end
    |         # OR
    [.!?]     # before one of these three characters
 )            #
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for: Array ( [0] => hello1 [1] => . [2] => hello2 [3] => . [4] => )

Comment: It still captures an empty string. Array ( [0] => hello1. [1] => hello2. [2] => )

Comment: It only doesn't capture the last empty string. Any empty strings after that it still captures. $inputX = "hello1?hello2????????"; Array ( [0] => hello1? [1] => hello2? [2] => ? [3] => ? [4] => ? [5] => ? [6] => ? [7] => ? [8] => ? )

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect.

Comment: `\b` prevents a match before any non-word character (not only the end of the string). Using this way,  your pattern may miss several positions in the string. If you want to avoid empty match, you only need to use the fourth parameter of `preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. You are right. I rolled back the edition.

Comment: Your pattern was good, except the `\b`, if you write: `$parts = preg_split('~[.,?!]+\K~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`, it works well too. And to be more rigorous the source string must be trimmed first.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. I like to solve it all with the pattern, but yeah, nice to know this php-feature.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Wow! This is awesome! What does the `++` exactly?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Also, if you post it as answer I will be glad to upvote it.

Comment: It's a possessive quantifier, the same than `+` except that it forbids the regex engine to backtrack. (a possessive quantifier doesn't give character back). in the same way you can use `?+`, `*+` or `{m,n}+`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Really nice pattern !!